# Fancybox 2: Any way of opening iframe without showing it?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox 2 for my web application. I read its online documenation, but failed to find a way of opening iframe without showing it to a user.

The reason for my inquiry is that when a regular page is loaded, I would like to make a Fancybox iframe get loaded too without a user's notice. When the user clicks  on a link on the page that will trigger Fancybox to show the iframe, I would like to make it simply visible. I hope this would greatly improve user experience in terms of speed.

Any ideas or links would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could, for example, simply create hidden iframe element and display it as any other "inline" element using fancyBox.

Comment: Hi Janis, I added a hidden iframe and when the parent page is loaded, it is loaded too. Then I was able to use Fancybox to open it as "inline" element. But, the display, mangement of its content through Fancybox call backs got complicated, etc. Not going to pursue this approach. Thanks for help.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKopWK But maybe you could just open iframe as usually using fancyBox, but add iframe inside hidden element, too. Then browser will preload it.

Comment: I tested your approach with Fancybox 2. Somehow the height of the iFrame does not use the full height of the containing div. Seems I may have to upgrade the app to fancybox 3.